# Exclude admins from query get posts

Tags: functions, get-posts

We are using this code to see if the user has posted, however we wish to exclude admins. Currently if the role is admin, the function returns a post count.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'author' => get_the_author_meta('ID'),
    'fields' => 'ids',
);
$wp_posts = get_posts($args);
if(count($wp_posts)) : ?>
```

I tried `'role' => 'contributor'` in the `$args` but the admin is still being included.

Comment: So you don't want any of this code to run if the current user is an admin? There are no role related options for `get_posts`, but for what you want to do the `get_posts` call is irrelevant, just check if the author is an administrator and wrap the whole thing in an if statement. I also edited your questions code example as it was all smushed on to a single line, and was unreadable. Please put 1 thing per line so it's readable, and indent properly, don't try to save space

Comment: Toms suggestion is probably the best option. Maybe wrap this statement around your query:     if( is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
  // DO QUERY
}

Comment: I am using this code to output the authors bio, in the wp-single.php - So I am not sure if I can use your suggestion. I will prob need some code inside the IF argument to check if the article was created by the admin ?